# How to setup optional parameters in mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am in a new project and I'm designing the URL structure, 
the thing is I want URLs look like this:
`/category-23/keyword/5/`
Where the normal page is:
`/search.php?q=keyword&cat=23&page=5`
So my question is, *cat* and *page* fields, must be optional, I mean if I go to `/keyword` it should be 
`/search.php?q=keyword` (page 1)
and if I go to
`/category/keyword` should be:
`/search.php?q=keyword&cat=category&p=1`
and also if I go to
`/keyword/5/` it must be: `/search.php?q=keyword&p=5`

Now I have my .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ search.php?q=$2&cat=$1&page=$3 [L]
```

I cannot make it working and the CSS / image files don't load.
I'd thank a lot who could give me a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with four rules, one for each case:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ search.php?q=$1
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)$ search.php?q=$2&p=$1
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ search.php?q=$2&cat=$1&p=1
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)$ search.php?q=$2&cat=$1&p=$3
```

And with this rule in front of the other rules, any request that can be mapped onto existing files will be passed through:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Now your last issue, that externally linked resources cannot be found, is due to that you’re probably using relative URL paths like `css/style.css` or `./css/style.css`. These relative references are resolved from the base URL path that is the URL path of the URL of the document the references are used in. So in case `/category/keyword` is requested, a relative reference like `css/style.css` is resolved to `/category/keyword/css/style.css` and not `/css/style.css`. Using the absolute URL path `/css/style.css` makes it independent from the actual base URL path

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Gumbo! Finally my .htaccess is like this: RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ search.php?q=$1
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)$ search.php?q=$1&p=$2
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ search.php?q=$2&cat=$1&p=1
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)$ search.php?q=$2&cat=$1&p=$3

Answer (score 1):

While i know this was answered succinctly by @Gumbo a few months back, I ran into a similar issue recently... and didn't want to include full/absolute paths in my app, to keep it dynamic and not having a bunch APP_PATH (php) vars all over the place... so I just added a base[href] html tag with the

like so...

```
<base href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST];?><?php echo APP_PATH;?>"/>
```

Hoping that helps others... and this is not trying to discount @Gumbo's reply in the least... they're right-e-o on :).

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

in @Gumbo's answer above? Works with me like that. If it *is* a file (like CSS), let it pass through.