# How to rewrite these urls for country, state, city?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a site where articles being submitted from worldwide and I record the location of them as `Country -> State -> City`, for that I am generating URLs like:

```
site/location/countryname/statename/cityname
```

I have a single php file which can take care of coming request and gets values in query string, now the problem is how to write mod_rewrite so it can have URL like above?

PS: It should not pass empty values if someone deletes the statename or countryname, means URL can be:

```
site/location/countryname
site/location/countryname/statename
site/location/countryname/statename/cityname
```

But can not be:

```
site/location//statename/cityname
site/location/countryname//cityname
```

In above urls if countryname is deleted then statename shouldnt be treated as countryname. Reading file name is `location.php`

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried any rules from the thousands of [mod_rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mod-rewrite) questions we have? That's not overly specific, unless there is an (unmentioned) need for parameter mapping.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to setup optional parameters in mod_rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927527/how-to-setup-optional-parameters-in-mod-rewrite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have got a way to do that:

```
RewriteRule ^bylocation/([-a-z_]+)(?:/([-a-z_]+)(?:/([-a-z_]+))?)?/?$ location.php?country=$1&state=$2&city=$3 [NC,L,QSA]
```

This single rule can take care, instead of three rules.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write the rules where longer condition comes first -

```
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ page.php?site=$1&location=$2&countryname=$3&statename=$4&cityname=$5 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ page.php?site=$1&location=$2&countryname=$3&statename=$4 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ page.php?site=$1&location=$2&countryname=$3 [QSA]
```

Comment: No, this one is the easiest but will not work if I delete in-between values read PS in my post

Comment: and if you change the (.*) to MUST-CONTAIN_VALUE, I think it is (.+), and handle the deleted-in-between values in the coming rules - e.g. RewriteRule ^page/(.*)//(.*)$

Answer (score 0):

- First of all make sure there's no slash (`/`) between each slash. It's the `([^/]*)`.
- Then make sure it's **never** empty. It's the `+` instead of the `*`. So, now, it's the **`([^/]+)`**.
- Then stop immediately the rule once it has been validated: use the `L` directive.
- Don't forget to make the query string follow via the `QSA` directive.

Here's what your final rules should be:

```
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ page.php?site=$1&location=$2&countryname=$3&statename=$4&cityname=$5 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ page.php?site=$1&location=$2&countryname=$3&statename=$4 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ page.php?site=$1&location=$2&countryname=$3 [QSA,L]
```

And if that's not enough:

### Two hints:

If you're **not** in a hosted environment (= if it's *your own server* and *you **can** modify the virtual hosts*, not only the `.htaccess` files), try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)